# Using Select queries in python mysql as parameters for if/else block

Tags: python, mysql, database, list, function

Can I use the results of a python SQL select query as parameters for an if/else statement in a function?  If I have a DB with one column, and want to append the values of that column to a list for each row in the Select Query...I can't reference those queries in a function.  For example:

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="****", db="****")
cur = db.cursor()

selectArray1 = []
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE value = 'x'")
for row in cur.fetchall():
    selectArray1.append(str(row[0]))


selectArray2 = []
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE value = 'y'")
for row in cur.fetchall():
    selectArray2.append(str(row[0]))

def function(x):
    #----Question-----
    #if I try to print out selectArray1[x] or selectArray2[x], why don't I get
    # a return value?

    #Following conditionals do not work, why not?
    if selectArray1[x] == "some string":
        print "The first array equals the x query"

    if selectArray2[x] == "different string":
        print "The second array equals the y query"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    function(1)
    function(2)
```

Comment: Why not use the ORM in your code? for example you can use dataset library in your code

Answer (score 0):

Please see this link: [Convert sql result to list python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14835852/convert-sql-result-to-list-python)

Basically, you want something similar to this:

`list(cur.fetchall())`

Comment: Thank you for your response, but doesn't this "list(cur.fetchall())" simply add the fetched row into a list?  That is not my issue.  My problem is that I can't reference an element that I already have in a list inside of a function.

Comment: Have you tried my correction? I assume your issue is that `selectArray1.append(str(row[0]))` only ever adds the 0th index, while my code should copy the entire list.